# Swap two integers in ruby without creating a third

Tags: ruby

Swap two integers in ruby you can:

```
a,b = b, a
```

or:

```
b ^= (a ^= b)
a ^= b
```

or so:

```
a = a + b
b = a - b
a = a - b
```

Are there more ways to swap two integers without the creation of a third?

Comment: What's wrong with `a,b = b, a`?

Comment: `a = b.tap { b = a }` ;-)

Comment: Your second and third ways are clever.

Comment: `eval("a = #{b}; b = #{a}")` is another one.

Comment: What do you try to achieve? `a, b = b, a` is a common Ruby idiom for this problem - it is clear and easy to understand. Whereas your other examples will make developers need to think and puzzle to understand what is going on. I think there is no need to improve `a, b = b, a`

Comment: @spickermann, This question is sometimes asked for an interview. I think that the knowledge of a few ways to change the value of variables can show how well you know the subtleties of the language.

Comment: @Stefan, It is interesting methods! Something like that I was looking for.

Comment: I thought of doing it using complex numbers, but I have problem writing the complex number literal. Can someone try?

Comment: `a = b + 0 * (b = a)`, works for real and complex numbers

Comment: `a=a*b; b=a\b; a=a\b` also works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compilation of answers from comments.  All are welcome to add their additional answers.

1. `a = b.tap { b = a }`
2. `eval("a = #{b}; b = #{a}")`
3. `a = b + 0 * (b = a)`

Answer (score 1):

> Are there more ways to swap two integers without the creation of a third?

```
temp = a
a = b
b = temp
```

There are only two `Integer`s in this code, there is no third one created.

Note that several of the examples posted here fail this criterion:

```
b ^= (a ^= b)
#     ^^^^^^ this creates a third integer
a ^= b

a = a + b
#   ^^^^^ this creates a third integer
b = a - b
a = a - b
```